# Is there a way to setup queue listening for hangfire in the "ConfigureServices" method in an Asp.NetCore console application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

Using the host builder of Asp.NetCore, I'm trying to Change the listened queue of Hangfire using a method that i could use in the "ConfigureServices" method.

I was wondering if I could do that or if I was obligated to use :

`using (new BackgroundJobServer(options)) { /* ... */ }` from [The documentation](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html) or if there was another way.

Here's my main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HostBuilder hostBuilder = new HostBuilder();
    hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);
    hostBuilder.Build().Run();
}
```

and Here's what my ConfigureServices method looks like :

```
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHangfire(config =>
    {
        config.UsePostgreSqlStorage();
    });

    services.AddHangfireServer();
}
```

I expected `AddHangfireServer` to have an overload accepting an `BackgroundJobServerOptions` but I didn't find one.

Is there a way i missed an overload or do you set the listened queue another way completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: `services.AddHangfireServer();` will have an overload accepting `BackgroundJobServerOptions` as of Hangfire 1.7.5 ([As seen here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1463#issuecomment-512846065))

**Response for people with lower version of hangfire than 1.7.5:**

I looked into the [code](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/a604028fa8a75ea1a122f58464e0823a076e6431/src/Hangfire.AspNetCore/HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) of the `AddHangfireServer` method and they're doing :

`var options = provider.GetService<BackgroundJobServerOptions>() ?? new BackgroundJobServerOptions();`

So a way of passing the `BackgroundJobServerOptions` would be to register it to the IoC container before calling the `AddHangfireServer` method.

Here's my final `ConfigureServices` method :

```
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    //this was added
    services.AddSingleton(new BackgroundJobServerOptions()
    {
        //you can change your options here
        Queues = new[] { "etl" }
    });

    services.AddHangfire(config =>
    {
        config.UsePostgreSqlStorage();
    });

    services.AddHangfireServer();
}
```